# How does the browser download the source file from a video tag

Tags: html, http, html5-video

I am looking at a website that displays a video tag plays an m4a file. In the html the source url of the m4a file is given. The source url and the url that the player is being displayed are the same.

If I load up the source url in the browser it just loads up the same player. I can download the src file by right clicking on chrome/firefox and clicking save audio/link as.

How does the video tag download the m4a file from the source video? Shouldn't accessing the src url allow me to get the file the same way right clicking the player and selecting save audio as?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the video's url in an anchor. Wrap it up in a block element along with your video element to make look and feel less like a download link.

**Snippet**

```css
figure {
  width: 480px;
  padding: 10px 5px 15px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00e;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px sold #00e;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover {
  color: #0ff;
  background: #555;
  border: 1px solid #0ff;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <video src="http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/html5-video-article-demos/maui-with-words.webm" controls preload="none" width="480"></video>
  <figcaption><a href="http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/html5-video-article-demos/maui-with-words.webm">Download</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```